# Add Button to Notification

Tags: java, android, push-notification, alarm

I need a button in my Notification, however everything i find online is not working. I need it to cancel playing an alarm that will go off at a designated time. Can anyone link me some articles to read or tell me what code i should use in order to get this to work.

```
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

import com.example.oceansscheduler.MainActivity;
import com.example.oceansscheduler.R;


public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void showNotification(Context context, String title, String message, Intent intent, int reqCode) {
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, reqCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        String CHANNEL_ID = "channel_name";// The id of the channel.
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_alarm_24)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle())
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            CharSequence name = "Channel Name";// The user-visible name of the channel.
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
            NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        }
        notificationManager.notify(reqCode, notificationBuilder.build()); // 0 is the request code, it should be unique id

        Log.d("showNotification", "showNotification: " + reqCode);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = context.openOrCreateDatabase("NotificationDatabase", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM PersonalNotif", null);

        Log.d("Count", String.valueOf(data.getCount()));
        if (data.getCount() > 0) {
            data.moveToFirst();
            String NameOfNotif = (data.getString(0));


            Toast.makeText(context, NameOfNotif, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            int reqCode = 1;
            Intent intentNotif = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            showNotification(context, NameOfNotif, "Your Reminder is going off!", intentNotif, reqCode);

        }

    }
};
```

Comment: I think this one will help you <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43253721/notification-action-button-dosent-stop-the-alarm-ringtone">Link Here</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a button in Your notification, You need to use `addAction` function.

It requires an `Action` object which needs:

- an icon (oddly),
- a title,
- a `PendingIntent`

The `PendingItent` can encapuslate an `Intent` that can be a `Service` that will be delegated to cancel playing the alarm or a `Receiver` that will do it.

Let's stick with a receiver. We can create one - **CancelAlarmReceiver**:

```java
public class CancelAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static String ACTION_CANCEL = "actionCancelAlarm";

    public CancelAlarmReceiver() {}

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_CANCEL)) {
            // Here You will cancel the alarm.
        }
    }
}
```

Remember to register it in the Manifest:

```xml
<receiver
    android:name=".CancelAlarmReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.your.app.CancelAlarmReceiver.ACTION_CANCEL" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Later on, when creating a notification with a `builder`, You will have to provide an `action` leading to our `Receiver`:

```java
Intent cancelIntent = new Intent(this, CancelAlarmReceiver.class);
cancelIntent.setAction(ACTION_CANCEL);
PendingIntent cancelPendingIntent =
    PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, NOTIFICATION_ID,
        cancelIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

builder.addAction(
    new Notification.Action(
        R.drawable.ic_alarm_cancel,
        getString(R.string.cancel_alarm), 
        cancelPendingIntent
    )
);
```

This should make sure that a button will appear by Your notification and it will trigger the receiver and disable the alarm (or whatever You will make it to do).

Comment: Hi Sweak, sorry for repling so late. This may be a rather stupid question to ask, but when i enter `ACTION_CANCEL` and `NOTIFICATION_ID` it says Cannot resolve symbol. Do you know why this happens?

Comment: Yes, You have to define those variables. In Your case, actually, the `NOTIFICATION_ID` can be swapped with `reqCode` from Your code. In case of `ACTION_CANCEL` - it was defined in my answer, so take a look.

Comment: Thanks Sweak, it is working now